# Start cell editing in extjs classic grid

Tags: gridview, extjs

I'm using the Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing plugin to enable in place editing in of a grid cell.  In one case, I'd like to programmatically enter edit mode of a particular cell.  It looks the old way to do this would be to use startEdit method:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing.html#method-startEdit

But it's now marked as deprecated with the note:

> Use the grid's actionable mode to activate cell contents. Starts
>   editing the specified record, using the specified Column definition to
>   define which field is being edited.

The actionable mode takes a boolean that turns on ARIA actionable  mode on/off. I don't know what I'd need to do, after turning that mode on, to actually start editing the cell. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually [setActionableMode](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-setActionableMode) method take two parameters

```
@param {Boolean} enabled
@param {Ext.grid.CellContext} position
```

**How to get `CellContext`?**

```
grid.getView().getPosition(record, grid.getColumns()[0])
```

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2e06)**, I have created a demo using [`grid`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html), [`cellediting`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing.html) and [`setActionableMode`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-setActionableMode). I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        Ext.define('MyModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone']
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'myStore',
            model: 'MyModel',
            data: [{
                name: 'Lisa',
                email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-111-1224'
            }, {
                name: 'Bart',
                email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1234'
            }, {
                name: 'Homer',
                email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1244'
            }, {
                name: 'Marge',
                email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-222-1254'
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'My Data',
            store: 'myStore',
            columns: [{
                header: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                flex: 1,
                editor: 'textfield'
            }, {
                header: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1,
                editor: {
                    completeOnEnter: false,

                    // If the editor config contains a field property, then
                    // the editor config is used to create the Ext.grid.CellEditor
                    // and the field property is used to create the editing input field.
                    field: {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
                }
            }, {
                header: 'Phone',
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'phone'
            }],
            selModel: 'cellmodel',
            plugins: {
                ptype: 'cellediting',
                clicksToEdit: 1
            },
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            tools: [{
                type: 'plus',
                handler: function () {
                    var grid = this.up('grid'),
                        store = grid.getStore(),
                        rec = Ext.create('MyModel', {
                            name: '',
                            email: '',
                            phone:'1234567890'
                        }),
                        context;

                    store.add(rec);
                    //Get Ext.grid.CellContext of first cell using getColumns()[0]
                    context = grid.getView().getPosition(rec, grid.getColumns()[0])

                    //Start editing in first cell
                    grid.setActionableMode(true, context);
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!  Works great.The docs don't mention the second argument (nor how to use it), and they also mark the method as private (and yet suggest it is the way to avoid the deprecated method).

Comment: @Notre hearty welcome. 

Yes in [doc's](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-setActionableMode) it is not mentioned but in ExtJS 6.5 version is defined on [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-setActionableMode)

Comment: `grid.setActionableMode(true, context)` definitely worked, however, in my use-case, I had to put it in a 50ms `Ext.defer()`. I have some other async and rendering going on that was causing this to get overridden.